# HTTP request 301 and 302 error

Tags: php, http-request2

I am using the http_request()(http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/) to check the page status. Its working fine but in the time of checking the external links it returns 301 and 302 error.but those links are loading perfectly in browser.

For example:
      the link http://siris-implant.ch is loading perfectly in browser but in the time checking with http_request() it returns 302 error status.

please suggest us, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: `302` is not an error. It's a redirect.

Comment: See documentation: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3

Answer (score 2):

If I visit `http://siris-implant.ch/` in my browser, it redirects me to `http://siris-implant.ch/de/`.

So it doesn't load, it tells me to go somewhere else to find what I am looking for.

That is [what 302 means](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3). It is not an error. (Errors are in the 400 and 500 ranges of status codes).

You need to follow the redirect (by looking at the HTTP `location` response header) and see if the URL it resolves to is in an error state or not.

Answer (score 0):

All 300 responses are redirects.

Since release 0.5.0 `HTTP_Request2` can automatically follow HTTP redirects if `follow_redirects` parameter is set to `TRUE`:

```
HTTP_Request2($url, METHOD_GET, array('follow_redirects'=>true))
```

Or use `setConfig()`.